# c# Battleships minigame

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, matrix

I am a begginer.
I am stuck upon a problem about namimng the colums and the lines, differently than 0 to 10. something like this picture, the lines starting from the bottom 1 to 10 and colums from A to J.

[image: Battleships kind of board]

I've created a program that tells me if the ship is destroyed or not, after using some moves( in this image using move 5 c, in my program 5 2, counts as a hit, if all the blue squares are hit the program returns destroyed).

```
    char[,] board = new char[10, 10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] boardCharacters = line.Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 10; j++)
            board[i, j] = Convert.ToChar(boardCharacters[j]);
    }

    int countHits = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < 14; z++)
    {
        var attackCoordinates = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] attack = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            attack[i] = int.Parse(attackCoordinates[i]);
        }

        if (board[attack[0], attack[1]] == 'x')
        {
            countHits++;
        }

    }

    if (countHits == 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("destroyed");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not destroyed");
    }
```

What should I change and how should I change it?

Comment: You are mixing concerns, How you display a cell position and how its indexed in the structure are two different things. ColumnLabels = char[] {'A','B'.. 'J'}  etc. would be one way

Comment: Also you are going to struggle with more than one ship. A collection of Ships were each ship is a collection of positions, would be one option

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, for now, a ship is enough. How do I implement that display in my program?

Comment: @JosipJuros Well, that's one point of view. Another perspective may be (and that's the one most of the users here share), that as the one who is asking a question you should make it as easy as possible for a potential answerer to comprehend the content of a question. Be it with understandable wording or be it with legible images to support ... So it's not commenting off a high horse, but a hint to OP how to improve the question ...

Comment: Added a version of the image that both light and dark theme users can see with ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming your rows and columns is completely up to you and does not have anything to do with the indexes in the array. So when you print your board (something you don't show here) you can actually print anything you want to name your rows and columns.

The real problem (at least with the code you show here) is when reading your coordinates for attack. When you do

```
var attackCoordinates = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] attack = new int[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    attack[i] = int.Parse(attackCoordinates[i]);
}
```

you actually expect two integers, so if the user inputs anything else, it throws an exception. Furthermore, as you are directly using those inputs to access your array

```
if (board[attack[0], attack[1]] == 'x')
{
    countHits++;
}
```

you actually expect the user to input 0-based coordinates, which most users with no programming background will find very counter-intuitive.

For supporting something like `5 c` you can do something like the following

```
var ac = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
var c1 = int.Parse(ac[0]) - 1;
var c2 = ac[1].ToLower()[0] - 'a';
```

For `c1` you have to substract `1` from the input value, because your grid is named `1 .. 10`, but the indexes in the array are `0 .. 9`. For `c2` you can use the [`char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) type and calculate the offset between the entered character and the character `a`. To support uppercase and lowercase letters, convert the input to lowercase first.

Of course, this is just the basics without any error handling. You have still to care for that yourself. For instance if the user inputs some invalid coordinates which cannot be parsed to an integer or are not letters of the alphabet, not enough coordinates, coordinates go out of bounds with your array, uses more than one space to separate the coordinates, ... All those inputs will still raise exceptions now and you need to sanitize your input first, before going on.

Of course there is still much more missing, but this answer is only addressing the issue you asked about. For instance you are always playing excactly 14 turns, even if hitcount is already reached earlier. You are not preventing entering the same coordinates twice, entering the board doesn't check that there are exactly 8 targets, ...

Comment: and how do I make the integer start from the last line?

Comment: just reverse your first loop `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` -> `for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)`